# How to correctly manage workers in nativescript?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, web-worker, nativescript-vue

I am currently working on a project involving **nativescript-vue and typescript** and I must work with **workers** (im not much familiar with NS and workers). I've read the doc and tried the implementation given in the NS documentation and adapted it to the project but I can't seem to get it right... Indeed it works at first but after calling a few times the method that instantiate and manage the worker, the app **crashes without an error**... I don't know if its due to the fact that the worker doesn't really close after finishing its task or if there is an issue with the script itself...

this is a part of the code of the main.ts

```
import "tns-core-modules/globals"

export class Main extends Vue {
   worker: Worker

 onTaskReceived(task){
   this.manageWorker(task, this.worker)
 }

 manageWorker(task: any, worker: Worker){
   const NewWorker = require('nativescript-worker-loader!./worker.ts')
   worker = new Worker()
   worker.postMessage({
                type: "task",
                value: task
   })
   worker.onerror = await function (err) {
                console.log(`An unhandled error occurred in worker: ${err.filename}, line: ${err.lineno} :`);
                console.log(err.message);
                worker.terminate()
   }
   worker.onmessage = function (message) {
                console.log('{onmessage}')
                worker.terminate()
   }
 }
}
```

and this is the code of one of the worker (worker.ts)

```
import "tns-core-modules/globals"
import { error } from "tns-core-modules/trace";

const context: Worker = self as any;

context.onmessage = function(task) {
    const request = task.data
    console.log('[WORKER]: data from main received')
    console.log(request)
    # Here is the code that the worker execute when triggered
    if (result.state === 'done') {
        console.log('[WORKER]: work done - sending data back')
        context.postMessage({
            type: 'result',
            succeed: true,
            value: result
        })
    }

}

context.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('[WORKER]{ERROR} '+error)
}

export default {} as typeof Worker & (new () => Worker)
```

thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: You might want to follow the instructions from Ian, besides try using log monitor from Android Studio which might give you more details on crash, share the logs & correct code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few errors in your source.

1. You're importing `NewWorker`, but then instantiating `Worker`.
2. You're importing with a `.ts` extension.
3. You call `postMessage` before assigning `onmessage`.
4. You're terminating your worker after one single message is received. It will take longer to boot the worker than to just execute the function in your existing JavaScript context.
5. Your worker export is different from mine (maybe it isn't an issue?).

In `worker.ts`:

```js
import 'globals';

const context: Worker = self as any;

context.onmessage = (msg: MessageEvent): any => {
    (global as any).postMessage({output: `rx: ${msg.message}`});
};
```

In wherever else:

```js
import * as MyWorker from 'nativescript-worker-loader!./worker';

const worker: MyWorker = new MyWorker();
worker.onmessage((m: MessageEvent) => { console.log(`(out) ${m.output}`) });
worker.postMessage({ message: 'Hello, world!' });

// later: worker.terminate();
```

Comment: Also you should close or terminate the worker from within itself once you're done with it.

Comment: 3 is not an issue at all. The onmessage listens for the worker's thread postMessage, which will fire long after. Aldo, even if it was the same MessageChannel, message events always fire async, so you can add the onmessage after postMessage synchronously and it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response @Ian, dashman and Kaiido :) Managed to correct the issue with your feedbacks !